# Arraylist.indexOf returns -1

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, indexing, genetic-algorithm

Planning around with some computational intelligence algorithms, a new area for me.

For some odd reason, I'm having trouble when finding the index of a particular array.

So for example, I have two arrays, both parentOne and parentTwo of type Integer. I add 300 random integer values to both array lists between 1 - 300.

I then attempt to retrieve the value from the randomly selected index in the array between 1-300, so for example, select city may = 129, the code then should go to index 129 of parentOne and return the relevant value at that position, however, it returns -1.

The peculiar thing is that this completely works when looking for any index <35.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

```
private int[][] cycleCrossover(int first, int second){
    //tempArray to return
    int[][] tempArray = new int[2][numberOfAreas];
    if(cycleCrossover == true){
        //select a random city
        int selectedCity = 35;//random.nextInt(numberOfAreas);
        int parentOneCity = 0;
        int parentTwoIndex = 0;
        int parentTwoCity = 0;
        int parentOneIndex = 0;
        int index = 0;
        //used to store parent and exchange values as well as cycle
        ArrayList<Integer> parentOne = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> parentTwo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> cycle = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //Assign values to the arrays
        for(int i = 0; i <numberOfAreas; i++){
            parentOne.add(population[first][i]);
            parentTwo.add(population[second][i]);
        }

        System.out.println(parentOne);
        //get parentOne Cities into new array
        long count = selectedCity;
        //Determine my cycle contents
        while(count > 0){
            //Get the index of the first city
            index = parentOne.indexOf(selectedCity);           
            //Add the first cities index to my cycle
            cycle.add(parentOne.indexOf(selectedCity));
            //add the next city to my parents cycle
            selectedCity = parentTwo.get(index);
            //take 1 from count
            count = count - 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: `cycle.add(index)` looks cleaner... Anyway. Apparently 35 isn't in the list, or one of the other values

Comment: The error is clear, your `parentOne` list does not have the selected city.  Are you sure you added it?  By the way, where is `numberOfAreas` defined?

Comment: Hard to help without knowing `population` contents. Please see about a [mcve] or step through the code with a debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `indexOf` method of ArrayList returns -1, it means the object you are searching for within the ArrayList does not exist.

Comment: Thanks YWE, i found the error, it was because I was generating random numbers between 1-35 using a different variable, when I shoud be generating a number between 1-300 therefore, index couldn't find any element >35.

Thanks guys!